# Euclidean distance vs Squared

Tags: metric-spaces

So I understand that Euclidean distance is valid for all of properties for a metric. But why doesn't the square hold the same way?

Comment: Please pick an answer different than mine to be the correct one, as my answer deals with norms instead of metrics.

Answer (score 11):

The square of the distance does not obey the triangle inequality: $1^2+1^2<(1+1)^2$

Comment: I know it doesn't by why doesn't it obey it?

Comment: To show that the triangle inequality is obeyed means to show that it holds for _all_ possible examples.  To show that the triangle does not hold, you need only _at least one_ counterexample.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I think Scott explained the lingering question.

Answer (score 9):

You lose the triangle inequality if you don’t take the square root: the ‘distance’ from the origin to $(2,0)$ would be $4$, which is greater than $2$, the sum of the ‘distances’ from the origin to $(1,0)$ and from $(1,0)$ to $(2,0)$.